# Validating rest end point with enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the enum as below, in the rest call I will get "01" or "02" as params then these are valid, but if I get "09" then it's INVALID.
How I can validate?

```
public enum Day {

    MONDAY("01"),
    TUESDAY("02"),
    WEDNESDAY("03"),
    THURSDAY("04"),
    FRIDAY("05"),
    SATURDAY("06"),
    SUNDAY("07");

    private final String value;

    private Event(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass request param as a number

then it will be simple as the validation assumes the value from 1-7

Of course, you will also have to update the enum to numeric

If you keep the request as a string, you can parse it to number

This is topic example for parse to number: [here](https://stackabuse.com/java-check-if-string-is-a-number/)

Answer (score 0):

There is standard java.time.DayOfWeek. It has following method

```
private static final DayOfWeek[] ENUMS = DayOfWeek.values();
public static DayOfWeek of(int dayOfWeek) {
        if (dayOfWeek < 1 || dayOfWeek > 7) {
            throw new DateTimeException("Invalid value for DayOfWeek: " + dayOfWeek);
        }
        return ENUMS[dayOfWeek - 1];
    }
```

Think about using this enum instead of yours.
Or you could write the same method in your enum.
Or you could easily convert this enum to your like this:
`Day day = Day.valueOf(java.time.DayOfWeek.of(dayParam).name())` given that days names match.

And I think Spring will automatically convert "01" string to 1 Integer if you want, so should be able to use @RequestParam Integer.

---

Or you could do something much more verbose

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY("01"), ... ;

    private static final Map<String, Day> daysByValue = Stream.of(values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(d -> d.value, Function.identity()));

    private final String value;

    private Event(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public static Optional<Day> forValue(String value) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(daysByValue.get(value));
    }
}

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToDayConverter());
    }
    
    private static class StringToDayConverter implements Converter<String, Day> {
        @Override
        public Day convert(String source) {
            return Day.forValue(source).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse day '"+source+'\''););
        }
    }
}


@RestController
class ...

@GetMapping
void get(@RequestParam Day day) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add a validation method to your enum

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(Day.class).stream()
            .anyMatch(day -> day.value.equals(s));
}
```

Then check the value you get from the param.

You could also try to parse the value into a `Day`

```
public static Optional<Day> parse(String s) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(Day.class).stream()
            .filter(day -> day.value.equals(s))
            .findFirst();
}
```

or if you prefer an exception instead of dealing with a nullable

```
public static Day parse(String s) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(Day.class).stream()
            .filter(day -> day.value.equals(s))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No Day found for value " + s));
}
```